# ORDER BY relevance, while using parametarized values

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

i found the following query online:

```
SELECT company_title
  FROM companies 
 WHERE company_title like '%gge%'
 GROUP BY company_title 
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN company_title like 'gge%' THEN 0 
               WHEN company_title like '% %gge% %' THEN 1 
               WHEN company_title like '%gge' THEN 2 
               ELSE 3 
          END, company_title 
          limit 100
```

that works perfectly.
the thing is, i am passing a parameter as value, and then fails.
so the question is, how to use this query with parametized values?

an example for a mysql programmer could be to define a variable at top `SET @what = '%gge%'`
and then use it in the query.

Comment: The answer will depend on what language you want to use. As long as we don't know that piece of information we cannot answer.

Comment: i use c#, but i dont really think there is any relevance to the language i program with, since i gave a MySql example for the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `case when`  statement to the select part and refer to it the the `order by` clause by its alias.

```
SELECT company_title
       ,CASE WHEN company_title like CONCAT(@param,'%') THEN 0 
             WHEN company_title like CONCAT('% %',@param,'% %') THEN 1 
             WHEN company_title like CONCAT('%',@param) THEN 2 
             ELSE 3 
        END as relevance
  FROM companies 
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @param:= ?) as trick_to_set_at_param_in_one_go
 WHERE company_title like CONCAT('%',@param,'%')
 GROUP BY company_title 
 ORDER BY relevance, company_title 
 LIMIT 100
```

Comment: this still does not solve the real problem, passing `gge` as a parameter.

Comment: Just use like concat('%',?) to get the parameter in there

Comment: @Dementic, you can set the `@param` inside the select statement. _(because the cross joined select only has one row it does not mess up the output)_

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables in an `order by` clause.

You have to use Dynamic SQL, check this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html